# What are the most redundant tasks (authentication, social network integration etc.) in the life of a back-end web developer?

Tags: database, authentication, backend, mobile-development

There are various tasks that a web back end developer has to do while doing a project while making APIs in specific. For example setting up authorizations for various roles, setting up a push notification server(mobile applications) etc. I just wanted to know a few more.

Comment: There are various tasks that a web back end developer has to do while doing a project while making APIs in specific. For example setting up authorizations for various roles, setting up a push notification server(mobile applications) etc.  I just wanted to know a few more.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of freedom the developer has. If the path structure is not explicitly described in the technical task, then first of all the developer creates the basic structure of the server. Then it determines whether user authorization is required to access the requests. If authorization is required then what type it would be. Ofcourse, creating connection to database.

You need to describe more clearly your question to get more clear answer. It really depends on the purposes and type of server (HTTP server, Media server, e.t.c)

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention... I was talking about a web developer(http). '' edited ''

Comment: So it is HTTP server. Server that is working on serving pages, images. I supposed that. Then the first part of my answer is just about that. Authorization and database connections settings.